# File upload form is not uploading

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I'm running a small PHP project for school, and I'm trying to set up a form in which a user can upload a profile picture.

I tried working with W3Schools, but I couldn't get it to work with my code.
Here is the link to that page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

First I declare some variables:

```
$target_dir = "profilepic/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image_to_upload"]["name"]);
```

And then I move the uploaded file to the right directory. After the registration it gets checked using this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

I already set parameters in the the form so a user can only select image files:

```
<form action='index.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type= 'text' name='leerlingid' placeholder='Username' required>
    <input type= 'text' name='mail' placeholder='Email Address' required>
    <input type= 'password' name='wachtwoord' placeholder='Password' required>
    <input type= 'password' name='wachtwoordcheck' placeholder='Password confirmation' required>
    <input type= 'text' name='voornaam' placeholder='First name' required>
    <input type= 'text' name='achternaam' placeholder='Last name' required>
    <select name='sekse'>
        <option value='Man'>Man</option>
        <option value='Vrouw'>Vrouw</option>
    </select>
    Profile picture:
    <INPUT id='image_to_upload' NAME=image_to_upload' TYPE='file' accept='image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg' required>
    <input type='submit' name='reg' value='Register'>

    </form>
```

wachtwoord is password 
leerlingid is username 
voornaam is firstname 
achternaam is lastname 
sekse is sex

The project is in Dutch so sorry for the Dutch names.

The form runs correctly and I get 0 errors, but after a user is registered no file has been uploaded.
I'm using a school server, but if I'm correct the $target_dir should start from where the form.php is placed.

I don't know if file_uploads = On in the ini file, but I can upload my files from FileZilla so I thought it was. (I have no access to that file though so there is no way for me to check or change it).

If someone could point me to why it's not working that would be a great help.

Edit:

I now tried this code as well:

```
                    $upload = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file );
                if( $upload ) {
                    header("Location: good.php");
                } else {
                    header("Location: error.php");
                //echo "Error:" . $_FILES["image_to_upload"]["error"];
                }
```

But my code skips this entirely. It still doesn't upload the picture and just goes to the confirmed registration page.

EDIT: I fixed my problem. Look at my other answer. It contains my errors.

Comment: _“I don't know if file_uploads = On in the ini file”_ - then find out - ini_get or phpinfo. _“but I can upload my files from filezilla so I thought it was”_ - those two things have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other.

Comment: "I already set parameters in the the form so a user can only select image files" Be careful! The code on the client side can be tampered easily and hackers could upload malicious code to take over your server if you don't check the file on the server side (in your php code).

Comment: The name of your file upload field is _not_ `image_to_upload`. Fix your HTML.

Comment: well thanks I'll try those, also like I said I wasn't sure so thanks for clarifying. @Null it's only for a school project so unless my teacher wants to hack my website that isn't really an issue as it's not part of the assignment I just wanted a higher grade. thanks I didn't see that

Comment: Your teacher will not hack your website, but I suggest you to take the habit to check uploaded files (or all other user inputs) server side too. It is something quiet essential in development, and even more if you are planning to have a dev job.

Comment: well I'm not planning on doing anything with Php but I do want to study game programming in C++ so I'll keep it in mind

Comment: alright @04FS I just checked and file_uploads is on

Comment: Did you fix the file input field name in your HTML …? Your script expects to find the uploaded file in `$_FILES["image_to_upload"]`, but that won’t happen, as long as the form field name is `image_to_upload'`

Comment: to what should I change it then? I'm not entirely sure what it should be then

Comment: To `NAME='image_to_upload'`, or `NAME="image_to_upload"`, or `NAME=image_to_upload` … just _not_ with an attribute value delimiter at the end, that doesn’t have a match at the start to begin with - because that is currently making it _part of_ the attribute value.

Comment: dude you're the man I didn't see that i missed one ' at the front it's still not working though. now my form will load the index.php page from the form instead of using the header I put in the php code

Comment: @YvalsonDronkers I don't know what makes you think so because I didn't, and I don't think your question gets downvoted at all. But I do feel it is not appropriate to just assume me did this.

Comment: @Null I also didn't know who did it I'm sorry that I said that that's why I said I'm not sure because it was downvoted and I really wanted to know why so I thought I'd ask in the case that it was you, again I'm sorry for assuming that's a bit immature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the help of @04FS. I wrongly changed "name" to "image_to_upload" in the $target_file variable after changing that back to "name" and adding the missing ' to the HTML code it worked and successfully uploaded the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the folder that will receive the files has write permissions?

Edit the code to be as follows:

```php
$upload = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file );

if( $upload ) {
  echo "Success!";
} else {
  echo "Error:" . $_FILES["image_to_upload"]["error"];
}
```

This will return all errors.

Comment: I made the folder myself using filezilla I'll try it anyway though because another person told me that filezilla has nothing to do with php